# Scaling models influences position in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

The scale of my models seems to changed their positions, but I don't know why. I am doing it in the S-R-T order. The blue plane has (0,0,0) as it's origin.

The model matrix is calculated like this:

```cpp
// set model matrix
glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4( 1.0f );

// scale
model = glm::scale( model, _entity.Scale );

// rotate
model = glm::rotate( model, glm::radians( _entity.Rotation.x ), glm::vec3( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f ) );
model = glm::rotate( model, glm::radians( _entity.Rotation.y ), glm::vec3( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f ) );
model = glm::rotate( model, glm::radians( _entity.Rotation.z ), glm::vec3( 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f ) );

// translate
model = glm::translate( model, _entity.Position );

Shader::setMat4( _shader, "model", model );
```

In the shader it looks like this:

```
vs_out.FragPos = vec3(model * vec4(aPos, 1.0));
vs_out.Normal = mat3(transpose(inverse(model))) * aNormal;  
vs_out.TexCoord = aTexCoord;

gl_Position = projection * view * vec4(vs_out.FragPos, 1.0);
```

The first picture is with 1.0 scale, the second with 10.0 scale:

[image: 0.5scale]

[image: 1.0scale]

Comment: I wasnt sure about this, so I already tried it. But it seemed to influence the position aswell. I'll update the post in a few minutes

Comment: Where is (0, 0, 0)? Is it at the bottom or in the center of the object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am doing it in the S-R-T order.

No. You do it in the order T-R-S. The order S-R-T is `p' = translation * rotation * scale * p`. You have to read it from right to left.

```cpp
// set model matrix
glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4( 1.0f );

//translate
model = glm::translate( model, _entity.Position );

// rotate
model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(_entity.Rotation.x), glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(_entity.Rotation.y), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(_entity.Rotation.z), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));

//scale
model = glm::scale(model, _entity.Scale);

Shader::setMat4( _shader, "model", model );
```